# Python Random Slice Idiom

Tags: python, random, slice

Is there a pythonic way to slice a sequence type such that the returned slice is of **random length** and in **random order**?  For example, something like:

```
>>> l=["a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> rs=l[*:*]
>>> rs
['e','c']
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about...

```
random.sample(l, random.randint(1, len(l)))
```

Quick link to docs for the random module can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html).

Answer (score 5):

There's a subtle distinction that neither your question nor the other answers address, so I feel I should point it out. It's illustrated by the example below.

```
>>> random.sample(range(10), 5)
[9, 2, 3, 6, 4]
>>> random.sample(range(10)[:5], 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

As you can see from the output, the first version doesn't "slice" the list, but only samples it, so the return values can be from anywhere in the list. If you literally want a "slice" of the list -- that is, if you want to constrain the sample space before sampling -- then the following doesn't do what you want:

```
random.sample(l, random.randint(1, len(l)))
```

Instead, you would have to do something like this:

```
sample_len = random.randint(1, len(l))
random.sample(l[:sample_len], sample_len)
```

But I think an even better way to do this would be like so:

```
shuffled = l[:random.randint(1, len(l))]
random.shuffle(shuffled)
```

Unfortunately there's no copy-returning version of `shuffle` that I'm aware of (i.e. a `shuffled` akin to `sorted`).

Comment: +1 for the insight on the literal "slice" comment and purposed solution.

Comment: @senderle ``shuffled = lambda p: sample(p, len(p))``

Answer (score 4):

No idiom that I'm aware of, but `random.sample` does what you need.

```
>>> from random import sample, randint
>>> 
>>> def random_sample(seq):
...     return sample(seq, randint(0, len(seq)))
... 
>>> a = range(0,10)
>>> random_sample(a)
[]
>>> random_sample(a)
[4, 3, 9, 6, 7, 1, 0]
>>> random_sample(a)
[2, 8, 0, 4, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 7]
```